# Alto K10 petrol Mileage reduced from 20 to 11 after replacing Battery

Tags: mileage

OEM battery was 32AH, but now replaced to 35Ah. But my car mileage just dropped huge right after battery replacement. My Alto K10 Lxi is just 3.5 yr old.

Comment: The mileage drop has nothing to do with a new battery, if there was a problem with the battery the car wouldn't run right. It's likely a coincidence, or perhaps someone knocked something like a sensor or a spark plug cable loose while doing it. Why did you replace the battery, was there some sort of problem?

Comment: How are you measuring the mileage (I assume you're talking about fuel economy here) ? If this is some sort of long-term average on the trip computer then it's feasible that the battery swap caused a reset?

Comment: My car got stucked in middle, couldn't start, indoor sensors was blinking, no light, no horn. Acid got spread over terminals. Sp. gravity checked found poor.  So I have to replace battery.

Comment: Agree with @motosubatsu here ... I bet not only a reset of electronic measurement, but also reset of the fueling tables as well. I think once it gets back to normal, you'll see your fuel mileage where you expect to see it. The increase in Ah of the battery would have absolutely no affect on mileage.